Calling Up Multiple Hosafot
I have only ever seen one Hosafa made, and it is always called up as יעמוד פלוני בן פלוני אחרון.
How would this work if there were multiple Hosafot? I would assume that the last Hosafa would still be called up as אחרון, but how would the other Hosafot be called up? Would it be הוספה ראשונה, הוספה שניה etc.? Perhaps it would be called שמיני, תשיעי? Would you just call up the Olim by name without specifying a name for the Aliyah?
Sources would be appreciated.

The phrase אחרון אחרון חביב loosely translates to "last but not least". The fact that you double up the word אחרון to me implies that just one אחרון doesn't necessarily mean the very last

In my shul on such occasions the gabbai calls

יעמוד פלוני בן פלוני הוספה א
יעמוד פלוני בן פלוני הוספה ב
יעמוד פלוני בן פלוני הוספה ג

and so on. The last one is אחרון.

I usually hear הוספה ראשונה then הוספה שניה etc. Do you hear it pronounced Alef, Bet, Gimmel, etc.?

@DoubleAA I did.

I have heard in various shuls the gabbai calling up people for multiple hosafot using just their name, without any number or description of which aliyah they are receiving. The final aliyah (before maftir) is then called up as peloni ben peloni acharon.
